# Unable to download windows Pokerstars installer

Tags: kubuntu, installer

On the main page of the site i clicked on `Download Pokerstars` which direct me to another page where i have four option for download :

1. `Download now and start playing`
2. `Mac`
3. `Ios`
4. `Android`
   When i clicked on the first option the same page reloaded without downloading anything. The same result on the second and third option. On the fourth option when i clicked on it ,it started to download the installer for Android. I used to download three browser Chrome, Firefox, Opera.

My question is because i use Kubuntu 20.04.1 i can't download the `windows Pokerstars installer` ?

Comment: Add the link to site in your question

Comment: @Madhubala link to site    https://www.pokerstars.ro/